# Qt - how to defer call to QAbstractItemModel::data()

Tags: c++, qt

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data

If my data has high latency to access, how can I tell Qt to call `QAbstractItemModel::data()` again later?

Comment: Just return *something*, then later emit the [`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal once the data has arrived.

Comment: Or make it so the `rowCount` and `columnCount` methods return 0, then emit the 2 reset signals from `beginModelReset` and `endModelReset`.